# .fits Files for Exoplanets

Tags: observational-astronomy, exoplanet, fits

I am learning to use AstroImageJ software. And using this software to plot transit graph for Exoplanet orbiting the star. I want to know from where can we find the .fits file of target star ? I tried to download some files from NASA Exoplanets Archive but they are very less in number (only 1 or 2).

Comment: To me is not really clear what you are missing. In what way are the files you have insufficient? Care to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I mean to say there are only 1 or 2 fits files available for each star. So I can only plot two data points on the graph.